# Ruby redefine "and" keyword in class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, token, keyword, dsl

Is it possible to redefine keywords like `and` in ruby? I have some DSL code like this:

```
rule condition and another_condition do
  do_something
end
```

I would like `and` to just be another ruby method inside my class just like `condition` and `another_condition`. Is this possible?

Comment: IMHO redefining Ruby keywords is a very bad idea...

Comment: Just discovered that it is not possible. See my answer below.

Comment: To redefine a keyword you'd have to change the underlying C code and recompile, after which it crash because of numerous bugs you would have introduced.  In other words, forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords like like `and` and `or` cannot be overloaded (overridden).

This article explains operator overloading and specifies what operators cannot be overridden:

http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2010/04/operator-overloading.html

At the end of the article it states:

```
You cannot override keywords, such as "or", nor can you override:
&& & || | () {} :: . ~ .. ...
```

**Update**

As  Jörg W Mittag pointed out, that's wrong. `and`, `or`, `&&` and `||` are the only operators that cannot be overridden. `not` can be overridden via `!`.

Comment: Can you, please, copy paste the relevant parts from the source, so that we find the full answer here? Once the link rots (which happens rather sooner than later) users with the same question don't get the full answer.

Comment: That's wrong. You *can* override `&`, `|` and `~`. You can also override `.()` (it's translated into a call to `.call()`). You can override `not` as well, or more precisely, you can override `!` which will also change the behavior of `not`. And there is no *fundamental* reason why `and`, `or`, `&&` and `||` can't be overridden, it's just not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by language.

But you can always try utils like [this](https://github.com/rahulraj/virtual_keywords) one.